# eclipse: turn off automatically reloading of class files

Tags: eclipse

eclipse has  a very nice feature. that is when you debug, it reloads changes to your source files when you save the file.

what is the name of this feature?

is it possible to turn it off?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `Hot Code Replace`, you can disable this feature by disabling (uncheck) `Build Automatically` from the Project menu.

Comment: thanks! yes that is what i mean. but actually i still want to build automatically. just during the application is running i want to turn it off.

Comment: @clamp, unfortunately, HCR is tied to the "Build Automatically" option in Eclipse; the moment newer versions of classes are available, Eclipse will load it into the JVM being debugged. See, http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F